# How to convert floating point decimal separator from dot to comma in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have already tried the following:

```
discval = 2.833423
discval = discval.toFixed(2).toString().replace("." , ",");
discval = parseFloat(discval);
```

The output is 2 and not 2,83

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parseFloat("2,83")` will return `2` because `,` is not recognized as decimal separator, while `.` is.

If you want to round the number to 2 decimal places just use `parseFloat(discval.toFixed(2))` or `Math.round(discval * 100) / 100;`

If you need this jut for display purposes, then leave it as a string with a comma. You can also use `Number.toLocaleString()` to format numbers for display purposes. But you won't be able to use it in further calculations.

BTW `.toFixed()` returns a string, so no need to use `.toString()` after that.

Comment: Yup, you really need to know why you want to change the dot with a comma. Anything else than display purposes is probably a wrong approach.

Answer (score 3):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point
>   number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -),
>   numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value
>   up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding
>   characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
>
> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat
>   returns NaN.

`,` is not an expected character so the number is truncated to that.

It's not possible to change the representation of floating point numbers in Javascript, you will need to treat your number as a string if you want to separate decimals with a comma instead of dot.